# Knockoutjs very slower with 100 records

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I was writing a demo when I saw some result of my knockout page and I was shocked.
This are the results:
[image]

What I do is quite simple, when someone ask to load the data I do the following:

```
            self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.colors = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.productModels = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.loadData = function() {
            var buffer;

            $.getJSON('/Product/InventoryData')
                .success(function(allData) {
                    buffer = [];
                    buffer = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new SDF.Data.DTO.ProductDto(item); });
                    self.items(buffer);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    alert("error on load data");
                });

            $.getJSON('/Product/GetColors')
                .success(function(allData) {
                    buffer = [];
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(allData, function (item) {
                        buffer.push(item);
                    });
                    self.colors(buffer);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert("error on load colors");
                });

            $.getJSON('/Product/GetProductModels')
                .success(function (allData) {
                    buffer = [];
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(allData, function (item) {
                        buffer.push(item.Name);
                    });
                    self.productModels(buffer);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert("error on load product models");
                });
        };
```

all the server method results are cached and they are very quickly.
Colors and ProductModels are observable too because I want give to the user the ability to change the "color" or the "model" of a product for each printed item.
The amount of data that I load is just 100 items.

Following my html:

```
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: $root.colors, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" data-bind="value: price" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: $root.productModels, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label data-bind="text: qty">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="product-sell">Sell</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="product-edit"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

any suggestion other than "page it" are appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I found which is the problem but now I don't know how can I resolve it.
The problem is how I write the selects foreach Item. Probably there are repaint foreach item.
How can avoid that?

**UPDATE 2**

The best solution that I found is use the Knockoutjs If-binding in my markup: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Comment: Maybe I can get the colors and the productmodels together the items in my inventory but I don't know how much faster will be

Comment: What happens when you add in the html for the Select manually, rather than using knockout for those bits? Does it still take the same length of time?

Comment: In that case, maybe the best option would be to have all the rows displaying the current values, and add in editing functinality, where you either click and turn one row into an editable one, or you have a checkbox on each row and then a master row that you can change the values of that will be saved to each checked row.

Comment: that's what I have. The select for the productmodels are all disable. The become enable when you click on "edit" link

Comment: No, I mean just have text cells showing the current values. When you click Edit, swap in a Select to the cell, don't have them all there but disable them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got this online anywhere, or could you knock together a quick jsfiddle for this, as it really shouldn't be taking anywhere near that long!

Saying that, why are you looping through the results of your AJAX calls and putting values into an array?

Have you tried only making one of your AJAX calls and seeing what effect that has on the time? Is that most of the html that is on your page, or is there a lot more? I'd be interested to see if it is the data binding that is causing the style calculations and layout time to be so large, as it really shouldn't be.

Comment: the server is not online.
do you talk about the buffer array?

Comment: Yeah, the buffer array. For getColors, you're looping through the results and adding them to the buffer array, which seems rather pointless.

Comment: because if you insert each item in the colors (observableArray) I will get a fire any item

Comment: But why are you looping through the results, rather than just doing: self.colors(allData) ?

Comment: you are right I didn't think about that. it's valid just for colors

Comment: I'd do the same with the ProductModels, if I were you, rather than looping through the results and extracting the name. Deal with getting the name out in the constructor you're calling for ProductModels. But none of this should be causing all that layout and style recalculations that you are seeing as taking so long.

Comment: what about using jQuery.tmpl ?